# How to use session variable from parent folder in a wordpress php code

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have developed a website with login and signup. Inside that website it contains a wordpress blog int he folder "blog". What i need to check whether the user is logged in or not in the blog. So i can put button like "login"-if not signed in and "dashboard"-if signed in

In parent folder's php file, i wrote like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
.......
.......
?>
```

and i used the following code in wordpress blog's php file, to check whether user have logged and display username.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
....
....
?>
```

But it gives me and error like this and doesn't display the username

"Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\it-itech\blog\wp-includes\general-template.php:2343) in C:\xampp\htdocs\it-itech\blog\wp-content\themes\dazzling\header.php on line 42"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error occurred because the output was sent before the session was started you need  to go this page `header.php`: on line number: 42 where you have included the file named `general-template.php` and see it does not give an output before the session gets started.

Comment: try to find out why are you getting an output in the `general-template.php` on line no:2343,  see what is the code that you have there

Comment: the line 2343 says this 

includes_url( 'wlwmanifest.xml' ), '" /> ', "\n";

Comment: got it, that xml file is starting the output and also a new line character is included.

Comment: so what should i do to fix this?

Comment: remove from blog's php gile and go to header.php and put `session_start()` line of code before the line number 42 in header.php.

Comment: i tried that. Its working in localhost. No errors. But when upload to server, that session data is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

try to use this in you theme's functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
}

function myEndSession() {
session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: so add my code after this? what does this code actually do?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be editing your theme files. It sounds like you may have been editing WordPress core files. Your session_start(); should go in the very top of header.php in /wp-content/themes/dazzling/ and ideally with a check...

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Then you can use your session data - again you should check if its been set (isset etc...) wherever you like in your page templates, which in theory will probably be header.php again.

Comment: yes i did that, but still when i echo $_SESSION['username'], it doesn't give any output

Comment: If you... `var_dump($_SESSION);` just after that code I gave you what do you get? I assume you get something on the non Wordpress part of the site?